# Javascript: Building a cash register function and having trouble with floating points

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, floating-point

I have the following code setup for a cash register function I'm building for freecodecamp. I noticed several issues with floating points so I took some other peoples advice and added .toFixed(2) every time there was a calculation done on floating point numbers. The two problems I currently have are:

1. I'm creating a copy of cid so that I don't modify it and can return it when the drawer resolves to closed, but the cid gets modified along with cidCopy, even though I sliced it and never modified it
2. The one number I can't get toFixed(2) to work on is `changeObj.change[j][1] += value[x[0]];`. If I change this to `changeObj.change[j][1] = (changeObj.change[j][1] + value[x[0]]).toFixed(2);` I get the error `(changeObj.change[j][1] + value[x[0]]).toFixed is not a function` This turns a lot of the numbers into crazy floats but I can realistically pass the tests if I can get 1. resolved, I'd just like to know why it's doing that.

This is my code:

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var cidCopy = cid.slice(0);
  cidCopy.reverse();

  const value = {
    "PENNY": 0.01,
    "NICKEL": 0.05,
    "DIME": 0.10,
    "QUARTER": 0.25,
    "ONE": 1.00,
    "FIVE": 5.00,
    "TEN": 10.00,
    "TWENTY": 20.00,
    "ONE HUNDRED": 100.00
  };

  var rawChange = cash - price;
  var remaining = rawChange;

  var changeObj = {
    status: '',
    change: []
  };

  var j = 0;

  cidCopy.forEach(x => {
    if(value[x[0]] < rawChange && remaining > 0 && remaining > value[x[0]]) {
      changeObj.change.push([x[0], 0])
      changeObj.status = "OPEN";
      while (remaining - value[x[0]] >= 0 && x[1] - value[x[0]] >= 0) {
        x[1] = (x[1] - value[x[0]]).toFixed(2);
        remaining = (remaining - value[x[0]]).toFixed(2);
        changeObj.change[j][1] += value[x[0]];
      }
      j += 1;
    }
  });

  if (remaining > 0.01) {
    changeObj.status = 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS';
    changeObj.change = [];
  } else if (cidCopy.every(x => {return x[1] < .01;})) {
    changeObj.status = 'CLOSED';
    changeObj.change = cid;
  } 

  console.log(changeObj);
  return changeObj;
}

checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 0.5], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]);
```

Comment: `toFixed` is a method of a Number, and results in a String - so, perhaps `changeObj.change[j][1] + value[x[0]]` is a string?

Comment: It is not a string. I tested ```console.log(typeof (changeObj.change[j][1] + value[x[0]]));``` and it resolves to "Number".

Comment: I suggest eliminating floating point from all your calculations. Do everything with integers in cents. Only convert to dollars and cents when the value needs to be displayed (or parsed).

Comment: As I said in the post, I'm looking to understand why #2 is happening. I need to fix #1 more urgently anyways. Even if I was able to get #2 displaying correctly it still won't pass without fixing #1 which has nothing to do with the floating points. Either way, I'd rather fix it and learn than do a fundamental rewrite of how I set it up and not learn why that didn't work.

Comment: well, `changeObj.change[j][1]` is a number the FIRST time through the loop, but then it MUST be a string the second time, because `.toFixed` produces a string - you can "fix" that issue by `changeObj.change[j][1] = (+changeObj.change[j][1] + value[x[0]]).toFixed(2);` - note the first (unary) `+`

Comment: as far as your "cid" copy issue, that's because youi pass in an array of arrays, cidcopy isn't the same as cid, however, each element is referring to the same array, i.e. `["PENNY", 0.5]` etc  ... another quick and dirty fix - `var cidCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cid))` - so, overall, both issues fixed by  https://jsfiddle.net/k7qjmhfu/

Comment: So even when you slice a multi layered array, the internal arrays are still connected? That seems silly. It almost worked, but stringify changed all the numbers to text so it won't pass. They have to be numbers. I tried  ```cidCopy.forEach(item => {
    item[1] = parseFloat(item[1]);
  });``` but that left any numbers that were touched in the next loop as text for some reason.

Comment: It was the toFixed that was doing it. I added another unary + to the front of it to change the whole thing back into a number and it worked! Thank you very much for your help. This is the final working code for anyone curious: https://jsfiddle.net/dqw2czao/

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  let cashArr = cid.map(e => e[1]*100),
      converted = [1, 5, 10, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 10000],
      rawChange = ((cash - price)*100),
      result = [["PENNY", 0],  ["NICKEL", 0],  ["DIME", 0],  ["QUARTER", 0],  ["ONE", 0],  ["FIVE", 0],  ["TEN", 0],  ["TWENTY", 0],  ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]],
      change = {status: "", change: []};
  /*This loop will do all the math at *100 to avoid rounding errors, it runs through the cashArr backwards finding
  the highest denomination of each possible change it can until the change hits 0 
  */   
  for (let i = cashArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    while(cashArr[i] > 0) {
      if (rawChange - converted[i] >= 0) {
        result[i][1] += converted[i];
        rawChange -= converted[i];
        cashArr[i] -= converted[i];       
      } else { break; }
    }
    if (rawChange === 0) {break;}
  }
  /*This loop will go through the result Array and divide any number that's not 0 by 100 to get us back to the 
  proper format. 
  */  
  for (let i = result.length -1;i >= 0; i--){
    if (result[i][1] !== 0){
      result[i][1] = result[i][1]/100
    }
  }
  /*This if logic will check if we have zeroed the change (meaning we had enough proper change), if not, we send
  the insufficient funds message.
  */
  if (rawChange !== 0) {
    change.status = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS";
    return change;
  }
  /*This if logic will check if we had enough change as well as if result is the same as cid(meaning there was
  exactly enough change), if so it sends the closed message.
  */ 
  else if (rawChange === 0 && JSON.stringify(result)==JSON.stringify(cid)) {    
    change.status = "CLOSED";
    change.change = result;
    return change;        
  }
  /*Anything else will have to be we had enough change with change left over, so we send the open message after
  we reverse the results array and remove all entries that have a 0 for value. This creates the array needed for
  output.
  */ 
  else {  
    result = result.filter(e => e[1] !== 0).reverse();  
    change.status = "OPEN";
    change.change = result;
    return change;
  }
}
```

This is my submission for that cash register test. It is a lot easier to do if you don't 
try to math with decimals.